# How do I play a particle system when moving?

Tags: unity

I have a car that I move with a Physics-based movement (`AddForce()`, `AddTorque()`, etc...) and I have a simple particle system attached behind the car as follows:

[image]

I'd like to play this ParticleSystem whenever the car moves; I tried checking if the car's rigidbody's velocity was greater than 0:

```
if(m_Rigidbody.velocity.z > 0)
   m_ParticleSystem.Play();

if(m_Rigidbody.velocity.z == 0 && m_ParticleSystem.isPlaying) // velocity.z == 0 is unreliable, verified with Debug.Log
   m_ParticleSystem.Stop();
```

I then tried using Input:

```
if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0) // the car is moving along the positive z axis
    m_ParticleSystem.Play();
if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0 && m_ParticleSystem.isPlaying)
    m_ParticleSystem.Stop();
```

These two methods don't work, I'm probably making assumptions on how `Rigidbody.velocity` behaves (when you stop the car for example, it becomes negative, so the particle system would keep playing until it reaches 0);

Comment: General practice is to avoid comparing floats for exact equality. Very rarely will gameplay be precise to the 10^-45 level needed to compare exactly equal to zero. Does using a range threshold help, or is there still another issue here?

Comment: No matter what I try to do, the particle system doesn't start or stop.. Is this even the way I should be doing this?

Comment: Where have you written this code?

Comment: I wrote this in Update(); It's not how this should be done though, since a statement like `Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0` even if it was accurate, would result in multiple calls to `m_ParticleSystem.Stop`..

Comment: Are you familiar with the ParticleSystem’s ability to emit based on distance traveled? You may not need to do any coding at all. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysEmissionModule.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a range and selectively stopping emission seemed to work fine in my tests:

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0.1f) {
    if (!particles.isEmitting)
        particles.Play();
} else if(particles.isEmitting) {
    particles.Stop(true, ParticleSystemStopBehavior.StopEmitting);
}
```